# How to find execution time of a process on terminal using proc commands?

Tags: shell

I have tried the command time [program-name] works but I want to know if any proc command can help me because this command fails to return an answer if the program has an infinite loop. please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if it serves your purpose:

`ps -p <PID> -o etime=`

Reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7871

Comment: and if i want time taken for the program to execute completely?